# XML xsi:nil="true" value set but returning null

Tags: c#, xml, null, xml-deserialization, xsi

I have given XML doc:

```
<root>
   <element xsi:nil="true" />
<root>
```

Later on in code the element gets updated to:

```
<root>
  <element xsi:nil="true">some data</element>
</root>
```

No whey I try to deserialize the element in to an object the "element" property is null. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the C# code I use to deserialize:

```
XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
StreamReader srFile = new StreamReader(strFilePath);
MyObject obj = (MyObject)reader.Deserialize(srFile);

[Serializable]
public class My Object
{
  [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
  public string Element {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: How the element is updated to this apparently invalid state where it is null and has a value in the same time? Do you update a xml string manually?

Comment: `xsi:nil="true"` means you're intentionally leaving a nil element in place. If you then add data to the element, `xsi:nil` should be removed, because *the element is no longer nil, and therefore `xsi:nil="true"` is wrong, but you're still saying *this element contains no value on purpose - it's nil*. The issue is you need to make up your mind - either the  node is intentionally empty and `nil="true"`, or the node has a value and `nil="true"` is removed. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Wiktor - I update the element by deserializing the xml, update the "Element" property of the object and then Serialize the object back to the file.

Comment: If you set `Element` to `null` and then serialize the XML, what happens?

Comment: From [Xsi:nil Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69.aspx): **When deserializing an XML document into objects: If the XmlSerializer class encounters an XML element that specifies `xsi:nil="true"`, it assigns a null reference to the corresponding object and ignores any other attributes.**  And from https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil: **An element so labeled *must* be empty, but can carry attributes if permitted by the corresponding complex type.**  So to add content to your `<element>` you must remove the `nil` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do a nodeName.RemoveAttribute("xsi:nil") before setting the value. Seems like there should be a way to do this when setting the element value since the value of the element would no longer be null.